# Angular environment.ts problem JSON. However environment.prod.ts

Tags: json, angular, typescript, environment

I have problem importing json files into typescript. I have configured tsconfig.json according to the convention, but it still does not work in the environment.ts file, however in the environment.prod.ts file, the import works perfectly

```
environment.ts

import { domain, clientId, audience, serverUrl } from '../../auth_config.json';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  auth: {
    domain,
    clientId,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    audience,
  },
  dev: {
    serverUrl,
  },
};
```

ERROR -->
Cannot find module '../../auth_config.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extensionts(2732)

environment.prod.ts

```
import { domain, clientId, audience, serverUrl } from '../../auth_config.json';

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  auth: {
    domain,
    clientId,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    audience,
  },
  dev: {
    serverUrl,
  },
};
```

Its work ok.

My tsconfig.json

```
"files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
    
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "strict": true,
     "resolveJsonModule": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true
     

    
  },

  
}
```

I am several days, without finding why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the error.
Now mark it in console, but not in the file.

[image]

Comment: The rebooted EVC and continued with the same problem. I get the feeling that it is an EVC problem. I keep studying.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced a similar problem and found the solution on [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule). You need to enable following option:

> resolveJsonModule -
> Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. This includes generating a type for the import based on the static JSON shape.
> TypeScript does not support resolving JSON files by default.

So enabling this option in you *tsconfig.json* under `compilerOptions` should do the job:

```
"files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
    
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "strict": true,
     "resolveJsonModule": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "resolveJsonModule": true
  },      
}
```

Maybe you also need to enable [allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) to avoid eslint errors.